# Is it possible to use Solrj (version - 8.x ) client library against Solr server with lower version (7.7)?

Tags: solrj, solr8

We have an application which integrates with Solr 7.7 (currently 6 production deployments)... We are using Solrj API to interact with Solr. We are currently considering adding the support for Solr 8.x in the next release of our application...

Based on Solr 8 documentation https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/major-changes-in-solr-8.html it is recommended to do a complete re-indexing of the data to move to Solr 8, as it has major changes and deprecated features, this will have a huge impact (cost & time) on the existing projects using Solr 7.7. once they upgrade to the next release of our application...

So the suggestion is to consider supporting both Solr versions (7.7 & 8.x) in the next release of our application.

The question is: Is it possible to use Solrj (version - 8.x) client library against Solr server with lower version (i.e. 7.7)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be possible but ofcourse not recommended. What are you trying to achieve by doing so? What is the benefit you are seeking? Your question/intentions are not clear. What do you mean by "suggestion is to consider supporting both Solr versions"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main point is not to enforce the existing project (with Solr 7.7) to migrate to Solr 8 and re-index their data from scratch if they will upgrade to the next release of our application. I meant by the "suggestion" the option to support both Solr versions (7.7 & 8.x)... Now for our developer to build the integration between the next release of our application and  Solr 8.x, he need to use Solrj API version 8.0...

Comment: So the question is it technically possible to use Solrj API version 8.0 to interact with Solr Version 7.7? Or the API can interact only with Solr version 8.x?... Thanks

Comment: Well I still do not understand your situation but it could be me being dumb at the moment. But Technically it should be possible, of course not recommended, and it's pretty easy to quickly test if they work or not.

Comment: I will try to explain further :). We have an Enterprise Content Management application (ECM) front-end, which communicate with Solr (back-end) to provide full-text search using Solrj API version 7. Our current version of the ECM ver.8 is integrated with Solr 7.7. and have 6 production deployments. In the next release ECM ver.9, we want to integrate with Solr version 8 using Solrj API version 8. Now for the current projects, if they want to migrate to ECM ver.9, they want to stay on Solr 7.7, so I want to check if Solrj API version 8 will work with Solr 7.7. Hope this is clear now

Comment: So release ECM ver.9 can support the integration with both Solr versions 7.7 & 8.0... So the question is about the compatibility of Solrj API v 8 with previous version sof Solr (7.7). New projects will use Solr server version 8.... Previous projects will continue using Solr Version 7.7 and they don't need to re-index. We are planning to test this scenario, however I want to check if someone have such implementation and can advise if it works... Thanks

Comment: @FadiAqqad what did you find out? Is solrj 8 compatible with solr server 7.7?

Comment: I would also like to know, as I would like to upgrade to Solr9j for interacting with Solr8 clusters.